# Determining index of smallest number in an array using reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, reduce

The goal is to create a function that takes in two arguments: an array of non-repeated numbers, and a string (either 'value' or 'index') and return either the smallest value in the array, or the index of the smallest number in the array, depending on that second argument.

I really need to practice callbacks and some array methods, so I came up with:

```
function min(arr, toReturn) {  // toReturn takes either 'value' or 'index'
  return arr.reduce(function(sofar, current, index) {
     return (toReturn == 'value') ? Math.min(sofar, current) : arr.indexOf(Math.min(sofar, current));
});}

console.log(min([7,22,3,4,5],'index'));
```

It works when set for  'value' but renders the dreaded -1 for 'index'.

Where am I going wrong here syntax-wise?

Comment: what the second argument is used for? If you need to find index of minimal array element second arg looks odd..

Comment: it's the nature of the function: it looks at the second argument (a string) to return either the smallest value itself ('value') or the index of the smallest value ('index')

Comment: Oh , so its just a flag what should we return smallest value itself or its index in array?

Comment: Yes. Smallest value when toReturn == 'value' and its index in the array when toReturn == 'index'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When returning the index, you are comparing the index of the previous call to the value of the next member. In the first call, that will be 0 since the min of 7 and 22 is 7, which is member 0:

```
arr.indexOf(Math.min(7,22))
```

so the function returns 0.

In the next comparison, 0 is less than 3, and `arr.indexOf(0)` will return -1 since there is no zero in the array. All subsequent calls return -1, and since there is no -1, *indexOf* returns -1, *ad infinitum*.

I think using *Math.min* is inefficient, consider using the less–than operator `<` instead and remember the lowest index as you go, saving a call to *indexOf* also.

The following expects *idx* to be a boolean or truthy/falsey, which is simpler than 'index' or 'value'. The default is to return the smallest value.

```
function getLowest(arr, idx) {
  var index = 0, value = arr.reduce(function(pre, cur, i) {
    return cur < pre? (index = i) && cur : pre;
  });
  return idx? index : value;
}

console.log(getLowest([7,22,3,4,5]));       // 3
console.log(getLowest([7,22,3,4,5], true)); // 2
```

It may be an extra line or two, but I'll bet < is faster than *Math.min*. ;-)

Comment: You're right; the indexOf is invoked at each call, and I had intended it to be called only when the final (minimum) number had been reached.

Comment: Cool, so use say `var value = arr.reduce(...); return index? arr.indexOf(value) : value;`. But I prefer to avoid the call to *indexOf*. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible implementation with `reduce`
You provide to reduce object with initial state

`{value: Infinity, index: null}`

`value` the value of minimal elem

`index` minimal elem index

On reduce you compare curren item with minimal and if its smaller update object fields
after loop just return field you need by `flag`

```
function arrMin(arr, flag) {

  return arr.reduce(function(m, item, index){
    if(item < m.value) {
      m.value = item;
      m.index = index
    }

    return m;
  }, {value: Infinity, index: null})[flag]
}
```

Comment: Why initialise *index* to *null*? Since you set *value* to the highest possible value, why not set *index* to the lowest possible index (i.e. 0)? Or maybe  -1? BTW, this doesn't answer the OP: "*Where am I going wrong here…*".

Comment: @RobG just to avoid indirect association with `inArray` result if elem not found. But its ok to use '-1' as initial value

Comment: @RobG, Question title tells abstract question `Determining index ...` so my answer is a possible implementation how to reach this goal. About 'Where am I going wrong ..' i think its wrong approach in reduce callback, thats why i offer another one

Comment: There are knee–jerk down–voters who will make their presence felt if they don't see an explicit answer to the OP, don't expect them to explain why. Not me of course. ;-)

Comment: @RobG lol:) thanks for admonition ) Anyway, if OP will be interested in alternative approach it will mean that i didnt spent time typing, other wise i'll get extra Peer Pressure badge)

Comment: Thank you, Evgeniy. (I'm too new here to rate up your answer)